# jquery/javascript issue accessing object's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, object, google-fusion-tables

I have created a google map which is populated with data from a fusion table.
I want to display some of the fusion data within a marker infowindow.
my code is this:

```
                suppressInfoWindows: true,
                  events: {
                    click: function(point){
                        console.log(point.row);
                        console.log(point.row['PC']);
                        console.log(point.row['CuID']);
                      infoWindow.setContent(point.row['CuID']);
                      infoWindow.setPosition(point.latLng);
                      infoWindow.open(map_markers.map);
                    }
                  }
```

As you can see i am logging point.row in the console which gives me:

```
Object
BrID: Object
    columnName: "BrID"
    value: "RDI01"
    __proto__: Object
PC: Object
    columnName: "PC"
    value: "AB23 8ZH"
    __proto__: Object
﻿CuID: Object
    columnName: "﻿CuID"
    value: "143723"
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

When i try

```
point.row['PC'].value
```

i get the correct value 'AB23 8ZH'
but when i try

```
point.row['CuID'].value
```

i get 'Undefined'

Any ideas why?

Comment: Possibly the `point` variable is filled asynchronously. So it might only get a value assigned to it _after_ you tried passing it to `infoWindow.setContent()`. Try to put it in a temporary `setTimeout()` to find out if this is what's happening.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle (or a link to a live map) that exhibits the problem?  I suspect you want `infoWindow.setContent(point.row['CuID'].value);` rather than `infoWindow.setContent(point.row['CuID']);`

Comment: I think the answer(that unfortunately has been deleted) was correct, there is a hidden character, a BOM, before `CuId` [`U+FEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) . Can you give us a link to the table?